# Angularfire $save array

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to save a collection of data after i have updated an entry in the array.

```
    // Edit a post
$scope.editMe = function(message) {
  if($scope.textBoxMessage = "What good did you do today?"){
    $scope.textBoxMessage = "Here you can edit your post by entering a new message and pressing edit on the affected post" + "\n \n" + "Your post:" + "\n" + message.post;
  }
  else{
    $scope.message.post="hello"; //$scope.newMessage
    $scope.messages.$save(2);

  }
}
```

Ones a user have entered some text in a textfield i want to replace that with the already stored data. This by overwriting message.data with sometext. Since i read in data like this:

```
var list = fbutil.syncArray('posts/'+user.uid);
```

i also tried to simply say:

```
message.post = $scope.newMessage;
list.$save()
```

Neither of these two methods work but i'm sure it's a minor mistake.

ED:
According to angularFire api, visit: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-save-recordorindex

```
    list[2].post = "hello";
    list.$save(2);
```

should work but i have had no luck.

Comment: The statement `if($scope.textBoxMessage = "hi")` will always be truthy (not `true`) because you are assigning a value, not comparing values. To compare values, use `==` instead of the assignment operator.

Comment: Ye that is also true, my bad on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is how i solved it:

The problem had more to do with the if else statement then with the server code itself. The $scope.textBoxMessage is always true no matter what and this is what bothered me. Even if i say if($scope.textBoxMessage = "hi") it will be true.

I'm not sure why this is the case but feel free to comment if you have any suggestions.

This is how i solved it:

```
    // Edit a post
$scope.editMe = function(message) {
  if($scope.newMessage == null){
    $scope.textBoxMessage = "Here you can edit your post by entering a new message and pressing edit on the affected post" + "\n \n" + "Your post:" + "\n" + message.post;
  }
  else{
    message.post = $scope.newMessage;
    list.$save(message);
    $scope.textBoxMessage = chatmessage;
    $scope.newMessage = null;
  }
}
```